# Cronjobs error - MySQL server has gone away

Tags: database, error, magento-1, cron

we suddenly have an error in the cronjob.

error message:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:63:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away";i:1;s:1334:"#0 /html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(305): PDO->beginTransaction()

<#1 /html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(495): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_beginTransaction()

<#2 /html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(219): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->beginTransaction()

<#3 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(76): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->beginTransaction()

<#4 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(313): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract->beginTransaction()

<#5 /html/magento/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(112): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
```

…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Error comes due to your code script not reach the server Database.
you need to normalize your code script, also need to increase the server execution time. 
 Get your server execution time with 
To know about the server php features `phpinfo();` 
function and put a small code above your cron job file max_execution time also by

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 180); // Set max execution time explicitly.
?>
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. - But the the time was already on max_execution_time 360.

Comment: Then you need to normalise the Php script code. Can you share the code so that I may help you deep

Comment: The idea was great. I thing I've found the error. 
I have the value in Magento backend "Mark jobs as failed after 120" increased to 360 
Now it looks like it would run. Thanks Amit